# Does a quantum field theory have an effective single-particle action in the single-particle subspace?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, action

In non-interacting quantum field theories, the particle number is conserved so we can restrict to a given subspace of fixed particle number. On the single-particle subspace, the state will evolve according to the equations of motion and I was wondering what these would be. In order to investigate this, I thought I'd look at the path integrals and extract the action.

### Single particle quantum mechanics

Suppose we are doing quantum mechanics with a single particle, then the amplitude for a particle in the position eigenstate $|x_i\rangle$ to transition to $|x_f\rangle$ in a time $T$ is given by the path integral

$$ \langle x_f | e^{-iHT} |x_i \rangle = \int_{x(0)=x_i}^{x(T) = x_f} Dx(t) e^{iS[x]}$$

where $H$ is the Hamiltonian and $S$ is the classical action which is a functional of classical trajectories $x(t)$.

### Single particle quantum field theory

Suppose instead I was working with a real Klein-Gordon quantum field theory restricted to the single-particle subspace. Single particle states are $|x\rangle \equiv \hat{\phi}(x)|0\rangle$ which we can interpret as the state of a particle localised on the position $x$. If I now calculate the amplitude from before, we get

$$ 
\begin{align}
\langle x_f | e^{-iHT} |x_i \rangle & = \langle 0 | \hat{\phi}(x_f) e^{-iHT} \hat{\phi}(x_i) |0\rangle \\
& = \langle 0 | \hat{\phi}(x_f,T) \hat{\phi}(x_i,0) |0\rangle \\
& = \int D \phi \phi(x_f,T) \phi(x_i,0) e^{iS[\phi]}
\end{align}
$$

which is just the two-point Greens function and a path integral over fields. However, this is the amplitude to transition between two single-particle states, so I wondered whether I could write down something like I did for the case of quantum mechanics above as a path integral over *single-particle trajectories* instead, something like

$$ \langle x_f | e^{-iHT} |x_i \rangle  \stackrel{?}{=} \int Dx(t) e^{i \tilde{S}[x]} $$

where $\tilde{S}$ is an effective action describing the single-particle states only. As this subspace describes relativistic single-particle states, it seems plausible that this effective action could be the action of a relativistic particle in Minkowski spacetime

$$ \tilde{S}[x] = -m\int_C d\tau $$

where $C$ denotes an integrating along the trajectory $x(t)$ and $\tau$ is the proper time, however I have never seen this been done before and I am not sure if this even makes sense because of all the subtleties about the position operator in QFT and so on.

### My question

Is it possible to rewrite the transition amplitudes in the single-particle subspace of a particle-conserving QFT in terms of a path integral with a classical single-particle action?

Comment: You may be interested in [the worldline formalism](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0101036v1).